# Firebase Simple Auth Login using Ruby

Tags: ruby, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm trying to implement [Firebase Simple Auth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html) using Ruby. I tried a few ruby wrappers [Bigbertha](https://github.com/derailed/bigbertha) and [Firebase-Ruby](https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby) but non provides a solution to Simple Auth.

Can anyone provide any useful links or suggestions to do Firebase Simple Auth Login in Ruby

Comment: You won't be able to do authentication via a REST API. OAuth is necessarily a client-side functionality (you actually log in at Facebook/Twitter/et al, not on the server) and an understanding of how OAuth works would be a great primer here. To do auth on the server you will want to [generate your own auth tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html)

Comment: @Kato what after generating auth token. How do I login using an email and password??

Comment: @Kato OAuth is client-side..thanks; basic and fundamental point.

Comment: Note that we do have a [guide for creating auth tokens via REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth) for RTDB users now, which can be useful for IoT and admin apps.